# How to Style navigable page sidebar in Shiny using bslib

Tags: html, r, shiny, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to style my Shiny app page using `bslib` and wanted to make the sidebar similar to like this  in bootstrap [examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/sidebars/) but don't know how to implement the similarly in `shiny` using `bslib`.

**Question** :
How to create these kind of bootstrap sidebar, is there a direct function like `sidebar()`. After implementation of the bootstrap sidebar how can on click open different page in the main panel.

Sample R script :

```r
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
  
ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Example dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    varSelectInput("var", "Select variable", mtcars)
  ),
  card(
    full_screen = TRUE,
    card_header("My plot"),
    plotOutput("p")
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Instead of these var select input can there be a way to replace these with navigable page like in bootstrap example.

Comment: For multiple pages you can use [`shiny.router`](https://appsilon.github.io/shiny.router/) package, developed by Appsilon. Just add the links to your sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Bootstrap's navigation components](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) (aka `navs`).

With the help of the documentation you see the markup you need, and the functionality works out of the box without additional `JavaScript`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Example dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    div(
      class = "nav flex-column nav-pills",
      id = "mynav-tab",
      role = "tablist",
      `aria-orientation` = "vertical",
      lapply(LETTERS[1:3], 
             \(x) tags$a(class = paste0("nav-link", ifelse(x == "A", " active", "")),
                         id = paste0(x, "-tab"),
                         `data-toggle` = "pill",
                         href = paste0("#", x, "-tab-content"),
                         role = "tab",
                         `aria-controls` = paste0(x, "-tab-content"),
                         `aria-selected` = x == "A",
                         x)
      )
    )
  ),
  div(
    class = "tab-content",
    id = "mynav-tab-content",
    lapply(LETTERS[1:3],
           \(x) div(class = paste0("tab-pane fade", ifelse(x == "A", " show active", "")),
                    id = paste0(x, "-tab-content"),
                    role = "tabpanel",
                    `aria-labelledby` = paste0(x, "-tab"),
                    card(full_Screen = T,
                         card_header(x))
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Gif showing a navbar design and a click to the elements in it change the content in the main panel]